# Sending a JSON POST request from aws Lambda Function to a REST API

Tags: javascript, react-native, rest, aws-lambda

well, I was trying to create a new pokemon by sending a post request from my aws Lambda function to my REST API like this:

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");

// define our target API as a "service
const svc = new aws.Service({
  // the API base URL
  endpoint: 'http://189.159.115.72/api/pokemons',

  // don't parse API responses
  // (this is optional if you want to define shapes of all your endpoint responses)
  convertResponseTypes: false,

  // and now, our API endpoints
  apiConfig: {
    metadata: {
      protocol: "rest-json", // we assume our API is JSON-based
    },
    operations: {
      // get a record by id
      // example how to send JSON data in the request body
      createPokemon: {
        http: {
          method: "POST",
        },
        input: {
          type: "structure",
          required: ["data"],
          // use "data" input for the request payload
          payload: "data",
          members: {
            data: {
              type: "structure",
              required: ["name"],
              // the shape of the body object
              members: {
                name: {},
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

svc.isGlobalEndpoint = true;

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event);

  svc.createPokemon(
    {
      data: {
        name: "Blastoise",
      },
    },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(">>> operation error:", err);
        return callback(err);
      }

      console.log("new record:", data);

      callback();
    }
  );
};
```

I am unable to the post request... my MYSQL Database is not registering the new pokemon..
but I am able to do it from https://apitester.com/ so my REST API is working fine..

The only error that is remarking is on my Android emulator: `Invalid Lambda function output : Invalid JSON`

[image]

Does anyone has a clue how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

console log from https://apitester.com/

[image]

[image]

And console log on aws website:
[image]

EDIT #2: (Added response body screen shot)

[image]

Comment: Could you give us some Lambda logs or the response when you do it via https://apitester.com/?

Comment: @LiuChang I added them :) hope it helps

Comment: Is the client expecting JSON but receiving HTML? The `Content-Type` header of the response of API tester says `text/html`.

Comment: @BetoIGM I feel you got the wrong `Response Body`, please show us the response body. And agree with @Hernán Alarcón, `text/html` may be the reason.

Comment: @LiuChang how do I get the response body?

Comment: @BetoIGM At the bottom of your screenshot there is **Response Body**, but I can't see the content.

Comment: Ohh, it says [ No Response Body ] @LiuChang

Comment: @BetoIGM I guess your Android emulator tries to parse the response as `JSON`, but it's `None`. So you can edit your Lambda then make it response `{}` instead of `None`.

Comment: @LiuChang How can I edit my Lambda function so response is {} instead of None? sorry I am pretty noob

Comment: @BetoIGM Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant before. But I feel the problem is still that **Lambda function doesn't not response correct JSON format data**. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with JS so you can ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html to make it response something instead of None (Perhaps something like `callback(null, {})`)?